# Correct font-weight loads then changes half a second later?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have set my h2 font-weight as 700, when I load my page, my H2 tags load with the correct font-weight (700) but half a second later bounce to a much lighter font-weight which is incorrect.

How can I stop the font-weight from changing?

It might be due to a confliction between my theme’s CSS and Bootstrap perhaps?

You can see an example at: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-budget/

See the text- ‘How to budget – Table of contents’.

Sam

Comment: if you have a  custom css file then add 
h2.section {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}
 and check if it works for you 
and error is cause of  this link can't load at your theme  index
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genesis-extender-google-fonts-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=%7COpen+Sans%7C%7C&#038;ver=2.2.4' type='text/css' media='all'/>

Comment: I tried adding the h2.section as you suggested but had no luck?

Comment: yes because of JQ migration ver 1.4.1 installed.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by JQ migration ver 1.4.1 installed?

Thanks, I figured it out (see below), bit of a hack.

Comment: its a javascript file which allow us to use the deprecated functions of jQuery. Maybe recently you update your theme.. or maybe its comes with your theme file. I think you recently update your theme.

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, yes I did recently update. I think it came bundled in with Genesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallelujah! I managed to fix it.

I ended up changing the font-family just on the `<h2>` tag from: `Open Sans` to `Open Sans:700` I then threw an `!important` tag on it to avoid an overide and applied `font-weight: bold;`.

```
h2 {
font-family: "Open Sans:700",sans-serif !important;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Note to self - keep things simple and avoid too many stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

For a fast solution set your font styling important that denies any change.

```
font-weight: 700 !important;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried adding the following:

h2 {

margin: 1.8em 0 1.1em 0;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-size: 3rem;
font-weight: 700 !important;
}

But the issue is still occurring?

I've also tried: h2.section { font-weight: 700 !important; } again no luck.

Comment: Hm weird try to inspect with your browser to see why it doesnt get applied

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I've given you a plus 1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following CSS file:

```
https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/A.style.css,qver=2.2.4.pagespeed.cf.dNG5vHCgAf.css
```

is adding the following rule:

```
h1.title{
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Either add !important to your CSS as Rudi suggested, or be more specific with your css override like so:

```
.site-inner h1.title{
     font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I've given you a plus 1.